# Compacting a number scale using a logarithmic function

Tags: logarithms, interpolation

I have a range of values that range from 31 to 2147. I'd like to be able to represent these numbers on a graph containing 120 points. Smaller numbers are more "important" and I'd like more visual discrimination between 31 and 35 for instance than between 2140 and 2145.

I can linearly interpolate the numbers and make each interval 17.64 (so lumping all numbers between 31 and 47 into one point), but that doesn't achieve my goal. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this logarithmic ally and I don't have enough math to understand any of the articles I've found.

I'm hoping someone can help me with a transformation formula to apply to my numbers so I can achieve the desired result.

So I guess I'm asking if there is a formula for logarithmic interpolation?

Comment: "a series of values between 31 and 2147 that I'd like to map to 120 points." - can you provide a scatter plot of your points, for reference? Usually you'll be able to tell from that if compressing with a logarithm might be appropriate.

Comment: I don't have the data per se. I will be running a simulation and this returns data that I'm attempting to visually represent. I know the points will heavily skew towards the lower numbers. SO it'd be of more interest to have the lower numbers matching up exactly with a scale point, then having the higher numbers in progressively larger "buckets".

There may be entire runs that the highest data point will not exceed 60.